# Setting a selectedItem by parameter

Tags: combobox, zk, selecteditem

I'm trying to set the `selectedItem` in two different combos included in a custom component. I have a Java class which send the parameters to the zul through a map of `args (Map<String,Object>)`.

In this map I send 2 ListModelList and 2 Objects (`ListModelList<Object1> list1`, `ListModelList<Object2> list2, Object1 o1, Object2 o2)`. The lists are supposed to populate the combos and the objects select the item.

1. If I try to select the item by using the `selectedItem = ${arg.o1}` I got a conversion error, something like:

> can't convert `Object` ... into `Comboitem`

2. If I try to make a Comboitem setting his value with the object I want to select, I got the error:

> Not a child: `<Comboitem null>`

3. If I try to select the item by his index using `"selectedIndex = ${arg.index1}"` (assuming index1 is the position of the object in his list), it return an out of bounds error.
4. If I try to select the item by `onAfterRender="self.setSelectedIndex(${arg.index1})"` I got the error:

> Cause: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `self.setSelectedIndex(${arg.index1});`
>
> Attempt to access property on undefined variable or class name

If I use the `${arg.index1}` as value of a label it returns the expected value.

Comment: mvvm or mvc? can you post your controller/viewmodel. I can give the solution like that.

Comment: MVC, but the zul haven't apply to Controller, is a custom component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you put a `ListModelList` into the combobox and selections goes on `ComboItem`.
Selection of an item is now done through your model.

The solution is actually simple :

```
list1.setSelection(Arrays.asList(o1));
map.put("list1",list1);
list2.setSelection(Arrays.asList(o2));
map.put("list2",list2);
```

And send the map then.
If the list is correctly loaded into your listbox the selection will be correct.

**Note :** Custom components can have a controller to ;)